# Concatenate hyperlink and text fields

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database with two fields - one a text name, the second a hyperlink -I want to combine them into one text display with the hyperlink:

```
<td><?php echo $row_RegRecordset1['fed_reg_page']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_RegRecordset1['fed_reg_url']; ?></td>
```

The display would be:
Federal Register Page (column Name/fed_reg_page)
"23923 (76)" and when the user clicks on 23923 (76), it would link to the 'fed_reg_url' field "http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/FR-2011-08-24/pdf/2011-21454.pdf"

How do I concatenate the two fields into one for display in the table cell?

Comment: Downvoters please note there was code that explains the problem that was hidden because OP hadn't indented it in the text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text needs to be wrapped with an anchor tag `<a>` which is the link.

```
<a href="the url">the text</a>
```

so, this is the code you would need

```
<td>
    <a href="<?php echo $row_RegRecordset1['fed_reg_url']; ?>"><?php echo $row_RegRecordset1['fed_reg_page']; ?></a>
</td>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question and code syntax. But the above answer was exactly what I needed and works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function
so it would be

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1,field2) FROM table
```

Comment: I don't think this is what's being asked.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what is being asked then

Comment: It was confusing for me too.